# How to hide meteor server-side code from browser?

Tags: security, meteor

As a newbie to meteor, I found lacking security is one of the first impressions people usually have due to meteor's historic debut and that meteor has taken measurements to address the concern. Therefore I pay more attention to this subject as I am learning it. When following the [to-do list tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/try), I noticed, to my surprise, the `if (Meteor.isServer) {}` block is visible in browser. The tutorial dedicated 2 steps out of 12 to move client-side code to server-side to make it secure. But if server-side code is also visible in browser, isn't that defeated the whole purpose? How could meteor be a secure platform in that regard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial is using this simple technique to start things quickly, but hopefully there is a built-in way to prevent server code being sent to the browser.

Every code that you put in the `server` directory won't be shipped to the client.
Likewise, source code living under the `client` directory only lives in the browser environment.

This is detailed in the docs section relative to "Structuring your app" :

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

Comment: Thanks @saimeunt. I'll accept your answer. But meteor's insecure by default approach re-affirmed my impression. Until the tutorial has been updated and `(Meteor.isServer) {}` has been secured, I don't see meteor to be of production grade beyond a hobby project.

Comment: `Meteor.isServer` is just something you can use to prototype an app in a single file, for any serious project you'd structure your app according to Meteor recommendations. Just because the framework allows you to shoot yourself in the foot doesn't mean you have to do it, especially if the framework docs guide you into not doing so beyond quick prototyping.